# cat a file containing "?" in command substitution

Tags: bash, arch-linux, cat, command-substitution

To automate access to my scanner, I'm trying to `cat` the output of `scanimage -L` into a Bash variable. In fact I was successfully doing this until recently with `siL="$(scanimage -L | grep net | awk '{ print $2 }' )"` in my [Scan.sh](https://github.com/harriott/ArchBuilds/blob/master/jo/Bash/Imagey/Scan.sh), getting me addresses like `hpaio:/net/ENVY_5530_series?ip=192.168.43.249` stored in `$siL`. I've today noticed an odd glitch which I've reduced to a minimum example here following.

Given a file `lines` containing just this text:

```
LINE1
LINE2_this_string_containing_an_embedded_question_mark_-> here?itis <-_doesn't_appear_if_cat_is_invoked_via_command_substitution
LINE3
```

`cat lines` correctly shows the file, but

```bsh
$ L="$(cat lines)"; echo $L
LINE1 LINE2_this_string_containing_an_embedded_question_mark_-> <-_doesn't_appear_if_cat_is_invoked_via_command_substitution LINE3
```

(and the same if I replace `cat` with `<`).
Why is that word containing the question mark omitted?

Comment: Your exact example works correctly for me. However, you really should double quote your variables when you use them - `echo "$L"` in this instance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766). Quote your expansions!

Comment: Here, if `here?itis` disappears and there's no `herexitis` file in the current directory, it's likely you have the `nullglob` option enabled. I wouldn't recommend setting that option generally. See also [Why is nullglob not default?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803)